# In angular2 I want my component to talk to another component, how is this possible?

Tags: angular

In angular2 I want my component to talk to another component, how is this possible?

I basically have a component that needs to do a broadcast to another component so that that component can update itself.

I only know how to do this in angular v1.

I have no code to show, as I have no idea how to do this.

The components are separate and not nested.
How can I get them talking to each other e.g. an event or something?

Comment: You might want to read the documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: Do you have a link for parent to parent? I dont need parent to child

Comment: Same concept as parent - child. Communication between components, always think `service`

Comment: You can use observables to broadcast data to different components.

Comment: @JohnBaird you have an links for observables

Comment: @PierreDuc parent to child doesnt work because my 2 components are parent to parent

Comment: @AngularM doesn't matter, even if they were not related in any way.. always use services

Comment: @PierreDuc how do I use services? do you have an example?

Comment: service usage: [https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service)

Answer (score 0):

I have a login service that defines a loggedin observable:

```
private loggedIn$: Subject<LoggedIn>;

constructor() {
   this.loggedIn$ = <Subject<LoggedIn>>new Subject();
}
```

I then defined two methods set and get:

```
setLoggedIn(loggedIn: LoggedIn): void {
    this.loggedIn$.next(loggedIn);
}

getLoggedIn(): Observable<LoggedIn> {
    return this.loggedIn$.asObservable();
}
```

The logged in class:

```
export interface ILoggedIn {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  error: string;
}

export class LoggedIn implements ILoggedIn {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  error: string

  constructor(email: string, password: string, error: string) {
     this.email = email;
     this.password = password;
     this.error = error; 
  }
}
```

With that, you can be notified that the user logged in anywhere in your app by simply subscribing the observable:

```
constructor(
   private ls: LoginService,
   private ss: SettingsService) {
}     

ngOnInit() {
   this.ls.getLoggedIn()
   .subscribe(
      loggedIn => {
         this.items = this.as.getLoggedInMenu();

         var us = this.ss.getUserSettings();
             this.ts.setTheme(us.theme);
    });
 }
```